# Storyboard UIButton vertical alignment not working

Tags: ios, uibutton, uistoryboard

I have my UIButton's configured like this

[image: this]

and this

[image: this]

except when I build and test the app, they don't get correctly aligned vertically as displayed in this image

[image: this]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! For clarification purposes, is the third image your desired output, or rather the one you are trying to avoid?

Comment: Thanks! No the 3rd image is not the desired output. the desired output are in the first and second image, the third image is the result when building the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the `top` and `bottom` values for the `content insets` property in the `Size Inspector` panel.

Comment: Thanks! fixed it. Weird it did not work using the vertical alignment settings.